# Recovering external HDD with deleted partitions using Macrium Reflect?

Tags: data-recovery, partitioning

I did something so stupid and I wonder there is a simple way for me to correct it.

Here is what happened.

1. I wanted to upgrade SSH of my brother's laptop (512GB -> 1TB)
2. I created an image using Macrium Reflect (I did not have an USB-to-NVMe adapter) and saved it into a 5TB USB external disk.
3. I booted into Win PE environment of Macrium.
4. Selected the image.
5. Instead of the correct target, I have deleted (quick delete) the partitions of the 5TB external disk. There was a small partition and a large one (~5TB). I had not even formatted the disk before, the partitions were as they were the day I bought. Now it appears as unformatted.
6. I realized and quit.

Now I have the external disk with no file system but completely intact data.

7. I have scanned with EASEUS Data Recovery and it can find the "lost files", however,

So is there a program that I can use or something that I can do manually to recover the partition structure/file system (whatever) instead of saving the data file by file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **recommended solution at this point is backing up** the drive contents to another drive, because without in-depth knowledge you may easily make the situation worse by writing to the drive at this situation. So even if you want to try out restoring inplace, it's best to have a backup. In case creating a copy of the entire drive is not an option and to answer your question:

**Most likely you deleted the MBR or GPT header of the drive.** See the [UEFI Specification](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_9_2021_03_18.pdf) for further details. This means the data is still on the drive, it's just that the "table of contents" for the drive is gone and therefore the OS is unable to find the files. An inplace fix involves rewriting this header. You might choose **fdisk / gpt fdisk** to do that on Linux. But as you were already using a GUI backup tool from EaseUS you might be more comfortable following the [Method 3 at this manual](https://www.ubackup.com/data-recovery-disk/gpt-partition-recovery-0616.html), attempting to rewrite the header with a **trial of the Aomei Partition Assistant Professional Edition**.